# Add to cart button in up-sell block

Tags: addtocart, up-sells, product-page

We want to display the add to cart button to our up-sell block on product page.
I tried this code, but that does not work and brake down the page

```
<button class="button related" type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>'"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

We do use this same code for the related block on the page, maybe that's the problem?

What code do I need to display the add to cart button for the up-sell block?

Thanks

Comment: can you show your crossell product code,?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$this->getAddToCartUrl($_item)` with `$this->getAddToCartUrl($_link)`.
This should work unless you changed variable names in `upsell.phtml`

Comment: Great, that did the trick! :)

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f @Lord

Answer (score 0):

find the items.phtml file in module catalog using template path hints ,here you can configure each products type (related,cross cell and up sell) inside switch case statements.select the product type and change:

$showCart = true;.

I recommend to extend the module in custom theme directory.This worked for me perfectly in product view page.